# What is a thin web-based front-end for a relational database?

Tags: gratis, web-apps

We currently have a bespoke web app for managing static data. It is really essentially just quite a thin front-end for a database.

[image]

In the top-left dropdown you can select a table, which will be displayed in its own tab. Most items (tables, properties, columns, etc) have human-readable names rather than their raw database value.

Tabs are paginated. You can perform CRUD operations on the rows. Fields which are foreign keys will appear as dropdown menus. Others may be text boxes or a kind of multi-option select. It is aware of constraints and will highlight invalid values.

You can search for fields within a given table. Advanced search lets you specify queries such as 'field A contains B', 'field C starts with D' and combine them.

It works quite well but is not very framework-y and so setting up new applications is a lot of work.

Is there anything open-source or free that is available which is similar to this? If it can be embedded in a Java Spring Boot application, perfect. If not, any language is fine provided it can be deployed as a standalone application with relatively straight-forward configuration. Database support for postgres or Oracle preferably but I'm flexible.

It definitely does not have to have all of features which I have described above - I listed them in order to give a general feeling of the experience of system, not because they are all solid requirements.

The only tools I have been able to find are too close to the database level, such as [OmniDB](https://omnidb.org/en/) or [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/). I would like something kind of one level of abstraction above this.

Comment: This is my first time posting here. I've read through the 'Asking' section help center but please let me know if there's anything I can do to improve my question!